# Difference between window.someRandomVar vs someRandomVar

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

If variable in not found in current scope, JS engine looks for parent score until it reaches global scope.

Now, in browser if I try below

```
console.log(someRandomVariable); 
// This throws ReferenceError as someRandomVariable is Not found on Global/Window scope.
```

But when I call it explicitly on window object, it shows undefined.

```
console.log(window.someRandomVariable)
```

As per my understanding, the former is also searching on window object only as it's not inside any function scope.

Why is it having 2 different behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log(someRandomVariable);
```

Javascript looks up the `someRandomVariable`, can not find it in any scope and throws the exception you are seeing. You are correct in saying that the window scope is searched - but you don't have this variable defined in the window (or any) scope. So it fails.

```
console.log(window.someRandomVariable)
```

Javascript looks up the `window` variable. It succeeds, then moves on to the `someRandomVariable` attribute. This is not defined, and so you get `undefined`.

It's probably worth noting that if you attempted to access an attribute of an undefined variable you would also get an error. Ie, try `window.someRandomVariable.someRandomVariable`.

---

The difference is that one is a variable lookup, and the other is an attribute access.